# Need to store the latest ID of my DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that is updating occasionally.
The ID column is 'auto_increment'.
For every request, I'd like to know what is the highest ID number.

What is the best way to save the latest ID?
Is it possible to define a global variable to stick along all script runs?

Comment: How often does a new row get inserted. If it's nearly every request then there would be no point, but if it's not very often this would be a good place to use Memcached.

Comment: I'm just curious as to why you would need this. If you need to get the id of an inserted row, after the row has been inserted you can call [mysqli_insert_id](http://www.php.net/mysqli_insert_id) to get the id. Please do not try to find the id yourself because it is possible you would get the wrong id when two rows are inserted quickly to the same table.

Comment: @Kuhn, no the ids are inserted from another script. I just need to read in that script

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT max(id) FROM `table` WHERE 1
```

You'll want to make sure to add one to this value since that will represent the latest added row.

ANSWER TO NEWLY EDITED QUESTION:

The best way to save the latest ID is to simply do nothing.  Don't include the id field as part of your insert and mysql will handle it correctly.  It will create the row and give it the next auto incremented int.  If you want to know what you just entered, you can run [mysqli_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) to get the id of the most recent insert into your database.  (That assumes mysqli driver with php, you didn't mention a language, so I just guessed, other languages/drivers support similar functionality).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Landon Why add 1 (assuming you intend to do this before the insert)? There is a risk that this will be inaccurate, returning a value that doesn't exist. Using `mysqli_insert_id` after the insert would be better, and is intended for this purpose.

Comment: The question was edited, the original question asked what was *going to be* the next id inserted

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store data in memory for efficient access you can use memcached with either the MemCache or MemCached PHP extension:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);

$memcache->set('last_id', $last_id); // Store the id in memory with no expiration
```

Whenever the last id changes just set it again. To get the id from memory you can do:

```
$memcache->get('last_id');
```

If $memcache->get returns false then your cache got lost somehow, so you need to get the last_id out of your database again and set it.

Note that (for efficiency reasons) you don't want to be instantiating a new Memcache connection every time you use Memcache, so either use some sort of Singleton pattern, or more preferably use dependency injection.

Comment: what do you mean by 'depepndency injection'?

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table'
```

and then read the Auto_increment column if you are reading before an insert

or `mysqli_insert_id` if reading after an insert